# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am getting the below error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
```

I am just trying to use the example of react JS from Thinkking in React.

The code is below:

```
class ProductCategoryRow extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<tr><th colSpan="2">{this.props.category}</th></tr>);
  }
}

class ProductRow extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var name = this.props.product.stocked ?
      this.props.product.name :
      <span style={{color: 'red'}}>
        {this.props.product.name}
      </span>;
    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{name}</td>
        <td>{this.props.product.price}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
}

class ProductTable extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var rows = [];
    var lastCategory = null;
    console.log(this.props.inStockOnly)
    this.props.products.forEach((product) => {
      if (product.name.indexOf(this.props.filterText) === -1 || (!product.stocked && this.props.inStockOnly)) {
        return;
      }
      if (product.category !== lastCategory) {
        rows.push(<ProductCategoryRow category={product.category} key={product.category} />);
      }
      rows.push(<ProductRow product={product} key={product.name} />);
      lastCategory = product.category;
    });
    return (
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}

class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleFilterTextInputChange = this.handleFilterTextInputChange.bind(this);
    this.handleInStockInputChange = this.handleInStockInputChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleFilterTextInputChange(e) {
    this.props.onFilterTextInput(e.target.value);
  }

  handleInStockInputChange(e) {
    this.props.onInStockInput(e.target.checked);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search..."
          value={this.props.filterText}
          onChange={this.handleFilterTextInputChange}
        />
        <p>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={this.props.inStockOnly}
            onChange={this.handleInStockInputChange}
          />
          {' '}
          Only show products in stock
        </p>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

class FilterableProductTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      filterText: '',
      inStockOnly: false
    };

    this.handleFilterTextInput = this.handleFilterTextInput.bind(this);
    this.handleInStockInput = this.handleInStockInput.bind(this);
  }

  handleFilterTextInput(filterText) {
    this.setState({
      filterText: filterText
    });
  }

  handleInStockInput(inStockOnly) {
    this.setState({
      inStockOnly: inStockOnly
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchBar
          filterText={this.state.filterText}
          inStockOnly={this.state.inStockOnly}
          onFilterTextInput={this.handleFilterTextInput}
          onInStockInput={this.handleInStockInput}
        />
        <ProductTable
          products={this.props.products}
          filterText={this.state.filterText}
          inStockOnly={this.state.inStockOnly}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


var PRODUCTS = [
  {category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$49.99', stocked: true, name: 'Football'},
  {category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$9.99', stocked: true, name: 'Baseball'},
  {category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$29.99', stocked: false, name: 'Basketball'},
  {category: 'Electronics', price: '$99.99', stocked: true, name: 'iPod Touch'},
  {category: 'Electronics', price: '$399.99', stocked: false, name: 'iPhone 5'},
  {category: 'Electronics', price: '$199.99', stocked: true, name: 'Nexus 7'}
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <FilterableProductTable products={PRODUCTS} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Looking for an answer for this.

Comment: check if you are passing `products` in the props of `ProductTable`, the error says it is undefined so maybe you missed that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code that you pasted is proper, it's **working** properly, run this snippet and check the output, problem will be somewhere else, you need to check your other components:

```js
class ProductCategoryRow extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<tr><th colSpan="2">{this.props.category}</th></tr>);
  }
}

class ProductRow extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var name = this.props.product.stocked ?
      this.props.product.name :
      <span style={{color: 'red'}}>
        {this.props.product.name}
      </span>;
    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{name}</td>
        <td>{this.props.product.price}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
}

class ProductTable extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var rows = [];
    var lastCategory = null;
    this.props.products.forEach((product) => {
      if (product.name.indexOf(this.props.filterText) === -1 || (!product.stocked && this.props.inStockOnly)) {
        return;
      }
      if (product.category !== lastCategory) {
        rows.push(<ProductCategoryRow category={product.category} key={product.category} />);
      }
      rows.push(<ProductRow product={product} key={product.name} />);
      lastCategory = product.category;
    });
    return (
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}

class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleFilterTextInputChange = this.handleFilterTextInputChange.bind(this);
    this.handleInStockInputChange = this.handleInStockInputChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleFilterTextInputChange(e) {
    this.props.onFilterTextInput(e.target.value);
  }

  handleInStockInputChange(e) {
    this.props.onInStockInput(e.target.checked);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search..."
          value={this.props.filterText}
          onChange={this.handleFilterTextInputChange}
        />
        <p>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={this.props.inStockOnly}
            onChange={this.handleInStockInputChange}
          />
          {' '}
          Only show products in stock
        </p>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

class FilterableProductTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      filterText: '',
      inStockOnly: false
    };

    this.handleFilterTextInput = this.handleFilterTextInput.bind(this);
    this.handleInStockInput = this.handleInStockInput.bind(this);
  }

  handleFilterTextInput(filterText) {
    this.setState({
      filterText: filterText
    });
  }

  handleInStockInput(inStockOnly) {
    this.setState({
      inStockOnly: inStockOnly
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchBar
          filterText={this.state.filterText}
          inStockOnly={this.state.inStockOnly}
          onFilterTextInput={this.handleFilterTextInput}
          onInStockInput={this.handleInStockInput}
        />
        <ProductTable
          products={this.props.products}
          filterText={this.state.filterText}
          inStockOnly={this.state.inStockOnly}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


var PRODUCTS = [
  {category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$49.99', stocked: true, name: 'Football'},
  {category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$9.99', stocked: true, name: 'Baseball'},
  {category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$29.99', stocked: false, name: 'Basketball'},
  {category: 'Electronics', price: '$99.99', stocked: true, name: 'iPod Touch'},
  {category: 'Electronics', price: '$399.99', stocked: false, name: 'iPhone 5'},
  {category: 'Electronics', price: '$199.99', stocked: true, name: 'Nexus 7'}
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <FilterableProductTable products={PRODUCTS} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id ='container'/>
```

Comment: I was invokng the render function twice which led to the error .Thanks for the answer